# add specific value to rows selected based on conditions with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a following dataframe:

```
id        fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
02     Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

I want to add Fruit to rows where Apple exists to generate a new dataframe like this:

```
id        fruits
01     Apple, Apricot, Fruit
02     Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear, Fruit
03     Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

How should i do it? Thanks. Sorry i makeup this example to represent my real problem.

Comment: Are those lists or strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Hack That Worked

```
fruit = np.array(', Fruit', object)
df.fruits + df.fruits.str.contains('Apple') * fruit

0                     Apple, Apricot, Fruit
1    Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear, Fruit
2                   Orange, Pineapple, Pear
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```

---

### More reasonable

```
df.loc[df.fruits.str.contains('Apple'), 'fruits'] += ', Fruit'
df

   id                                  fruits
0   1                   Apple, Apricot, Fruit
1   2  Apple, Banana, Clementine, Pear, Fruit
2   3                 Orange, Pineapple, Pear
```

__

To address comment, NA comes up where elements in the `fruits` column were not strings.  That implies poor data.  No matter, we can fill the NAs

Thanks [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094020/add-specific-value-to-rows-selected-based-on-conditions-with-pandas/51094159?noredirect=1#comment89177170_51094159) for improved implementation.

```
df.loc[df.fruits.str.contains('Apple', na=False), 'fruits'] += ', Fruit'
df
```

Comment: Also, `np.where(df.fruits.str.contains('Apple'), df.fruits.add(', Fruits'), df.fruits)`

Comment: For your first method: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'; and for second one: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: I don't know what's going on for the first one but its hacky anyway.  For the second one, see my update.

Comment: `df.fruits.str.contains('Apple', na=False)` ?

Comment: @jezrael love it!  I didn't know that one (-:

Comment: with no = False, it works perfectly. Thanks. Just one more question, if i want to add Fruit for those rows contains "Apple" or "Pear"/ 'Apple' and 'Pear', 'what i should change to your code?

Comment: Or `df.fruits.str.contains('Apple|Pear', na=False)`

Comment: And `df.fruits.str.contains('Apple', na=False) & df.fruits.str.contains('Pear', na=False)`

Comment: I appreciate your helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['fruits'] = [row + ', Fruit' if 'Apple' in str(row) else row for row in df['fruits']]
```

Comment: Thanks. I try your method. it says TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: There might be NaN values in the table.  I have updated my answer to deal that.